# C# Remove GridView CommandField Link from TAB order

Tags: c#, gridview, tabs

I have GridView with three columns one is template field textbox and other two are CommandFileds Insert,Delete.  Now I wish to remove TAB ing from CommandFields.
I need to TAB only over  textboxes. If I try to put `TabIndex="-1"` on `CommandField` I am getting error.

```
                <asp:GridView ID="gvStavke" runat="server" BackColor="White"  AllowPaging="True" PageSize="20" TabIndex="-1" >
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Unesi Cijenu">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtJedinicnaCijena" runat="server" Width="100px" >
                                </asp:TextBox>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:CommandField SelectText="IZMJENI" ShowSelectButton="True" />
                        <asp:CommandField DeleteText="IZBRIŠI" ShowDeleteButton="True" />

                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```